Android bindServiceAsUser equivalent API which runs on an executor thread
I have the current code which passes an executor thread to bindService API as below:
   public class SynchronousExecutor implements Executor {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable r) {
            r.run();
        }
    }

context.bindService(
            intent, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE, new SynchronousExecutor(), mConnection)

Is there an equivalent API for bindServiceAsUser that can be run on an executor thread like above?
context.bindServiceAsUser(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE, UserHandle.SYSTEM)

The problem I am trying to solve is basically onServiceConnected causes main thread race condition with binder calls when using the bindServiceAsUser call.text
I have tried putting the bindServiceAsUser call iself on ExecutorService Threadpool put did not seem to solve the issue. Somehow bindServiceAsUser internally puts everything on the main thread.
